# $Z^2-YZ-Y^2+X^2+2XY$ is an irreducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

How to show that $Z^2-YZ-Y^2+X^2+2XY$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\Bbb{C}[X,Y,Z]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $Z^2-YZ-Y^2+X^2+2XY$ is reducible. Since this is a degree two polynomial in $Z$ with coefficients in $\Bbb C[X,Y]$ it splits into a product of two polynomials of degree one in $Z$, that is, $Z^2-YZ-Y^2+X^2+2XY=(Z+f(X,Y))(Z+g(X,Y))$. We get $f(X,Y)+g(X,Y)=-Y$ and $f(X,Y)g(X,Y)=-Y^2+X^2+2XY$. Now plug in the second relation what you get from the first and find $f(X,Y)(f(X,Y)+Y)=Y^2-2XY-X^2$. This implies that $\deg_Yf(X,Y)=1$, so $f(X,Y)=a(X)+b(X)Y$. Now just calculate what you need and get $b(X)(b(X)+1)=1$, $2a(x)b(x)+a(X)=-2X$, and $a^2(X)=-X^2$. From $b(X)(b(X)+1)=1$ we deduce that $\deg b(X)=0$ and from now on write it $b$ instead of $b(X)$. We have $b(b+1)=1$. We also get $a(X)=\frac{-2}{2b+1}X$ and plugin this into the first relation we get $4=-(2b+1)^2$, so $4=-4(b^2+b)-1$ and from $b(b+1)=1$ we get $4=-4-1$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

You can see it is a cone. It is irreducible because its smooth part is connected and dense. Compute where it is smooth using the Jacobian.

Comment: I don`t know all this!!!

Comment: Try the alternative solution.

Comment: Be careful with the solution of Igor Rivin, since substituting a value for a variable means intersecting the surface with a plane. You may have that the intersection is irreducible but the whole surface was not. In this example you are getting lucky since this cannot happen because being quadratic in all variables there is not space for that to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, it is a quadratic polynomial in $Z$. Complete the square in $Z$. You will something like $(Z-A)^2+B$. For it to be reducible $B$ must be a square (over the complex numbers). But $B$ is again a quadratic polynomial in the remaining variables. If it is a square, it is reducible. Repeat the same work as before with this polynomial using another one of the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way: substitute some value for $Y,$ and check that the resulting polynomial is irreducible. My favorite value is $Y=2.$

Comment: I do not understand the idea.. could you explain a bit more.... Is this valid for more general case I mean Is this hold for a single variable case also..? Can I conclude $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+ a_1$ is irreducible by substituting some number and get some value which assure irreducibility? Could you please explain more about this..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik the univariate case is, in some sense, the hardest: the most direct extension to that case is Cohn's irreducibility criterion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohn%27s_irreducibility_criterion. But in more variables, it's fairly obvious: if a polynomial is reducible, then setting a variable to a constant generally keeps it irreducible (unless the variable is itself a factor, which is easy to check). See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_irreducibility_theorem

Comment: I guess you meant to say reducible in both cases or the other way?? :O you said irreducible once and irreducible in the very next sentence... Thanks for the link :)

Comment: Yes, I meant that specializing the variable does not (usually) change the reducibility properties...